# Redux: Why is using dispatch from store is not recommended

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using `redux` in a `phaser` and `react` based game, dispatching actions in React Components, Utils, and Axios API Calls. I know there are `useDispatch` hook and `connect` can be used for React Components, however, based on my own experience, I can use dispatch from `store` directly as well.

```
import store from 'my-redux/store';

const { dispatch } = store;

dispatch(actionCreator(1));
```

I use the above way to dispatch actions in Phaser Scene and Utils to change states such as `health` and `score`, and dispatch actions in Axios async API calls. It is convenient and light compare to using `useDispatch` or `connect`, so why is it not recommended to dispatch from `store` except for isomorphic app?

Reference for why not use dispatch from `store` for isomorphic apps:

1. [redux issue!916](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/916#issuecomment-149190441)
2. [redux issue!184](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/184)
3. [redux issue!362](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/362)

I even want to bind `dispatch` to action creators like this:

```
import store from 'my-redux/store';

const { dispatch } = store;

export const handleSetSomeThing = (state) => {
  const action = {
    type: ActionTypes.SOME_TYPE,
    payload: state,
  };
  dispatch(action);
};
```

Then I can call the above function like this without importing `store` or using `connect`, `redux hook`:

```
handleSetSomeThing({ health: 5 })
```

Any idea?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I follow you correctly, but wouldn't this cause incosistent state between react and redux? React doesn't get notified of any changes when you use dispatch that way.

Comment: The states among all places where using the same-store are synchronous.

Comment: The redux state itself yes, but not the iteration of the state that gets propagated to React.
Redux is a standalone library and is not connected to React by default, that's why you have to use the `react-redux` library. React doesn't know anything about Redux and vice versa without using that library. And in your case you are not using that library, so React won't get notified about changes.

Comment: In general, as soon as you start doing weird stuff that the library doesn't suggest (or actively discourages), alarm bells should start going off. The whole `store -> component -> action -> reducer -> store` cycle exists for a reason. There's a bunch of computer science theory behind it. If your issue is you don't like the fact that Redux is kinda boilerplate heavy, there's plenty of alternatives that could do the same kinda thing

Comment: there is a point in your question to why redux not producing an API like this that wont require you to connect or use hooks... totally agree... why using hooks for dispatches...?

Comment: That is exactly what I don't understand, why do we need to use `react-redux` or `redux hook` to connect to each other? I mean, It seems `store` is a place where I store my data, why can't I just use `getState` - the function derived from `store` to get my data? @JohannesKlauß said "`React doesn't know anything about Redux and vice versa without using that library.` ", What is the reasons React can't get Redux's state with `getState`, and what is the reasons Redux can't be notified if we use `dispatch` to send all the data we want to keep to `store`?

Comment: Why I am saying this is because that it seems Redux working well in my case, I have a Phaser-React project, and I tried using only `getState` and `dispatch` from `store`, I don't see any missing data or inconvenience.

Comment: Because the redux store and Reacts component state are independent of each other. They have nothing in common. You use redux to update some redux store. You can use redux with vanilla js, angular, vue, etc. Redux is a independent library that has nothing to do with react. That is why you need `react-redux` to connect those two libraries.